# Preserving elements on page during Hot Code Reload

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

If a user is watching a video, or streaming audio on a page in my Meteor app, is there something I can use to prevent that particular player element from refreshing/stopping/closing during a Hot Code Reload when new code is pushed?

Currently, if I make a change to the code base and a user is watching/listening to something, they will be interrupted and the player will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the onMigrate api (undocumented) to disable a hot code push if someone is watching a video:

```
function onMigrate (retry) {
  //Return [true, data] to allow it to hot code reload, data being anything you want to be available when the page reloads
  return false;
}

Meteor._reload.onMigrate("someName", onMigrate);
// or Meteor._reload.onMigrate(onMigrate);
```

There's also a [videocast](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-using-a-custom-onmigrate-api) covering this on eventedmind and a bit of a comment about it on github: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reload/reload.js#L81-L94

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of onMigrate (as you say, it's undocumented). The video cast demonstrates it fairly well, so I'll take cues from there. Cheers.